# How to stop audio from "warbling" when using SoundFlower

Tags: audio, bluetooth, soundflower

My system consists of a 2011 iMac running Mavericks, and using an external audio interface (iConnectAudio4+) along with a Bluetooth speaker and Airfoil to create a "surround" effect for music while I'm working.

The issue is specific to SoundFlower, which I must use or I can't adjust the computer volume at all (volume control gets greyed out).  My routing for this setup is as follows:

Mac Audio Output > SoundFlower > iConnectAudio4+

Airfoil's audio source is typically iTunes and its speakers are the computer, and the Bluetooth speaker.  When I have this set up, everything works fine, except that periodically audio will begin to drift and sounds a lot like a warped cassette tape.  It's very noticeable especially on any sort of sustained notes (pianos, voice, etc.).

If I remove SoundFlower from the equation and simply route System audio direct to the iConnectAudio4+, the problem goes away but I am no longer able to adjust the Mac audio levels via the OS.

In my experience getting this to work, I have to use Airfoil because any other solution such as simply creating a multi-output device of the audio interface and BT speaker, results in a significant and non-adjustable delay between the two.  Airfoil allows for dialing in the latency so that everything is in near perfect sync around me.

My question could be seen as 2 part:

1. Is there a way to use this setup as I have described but eliminate the audio warping?
2. Is there a different way to set my system up which would give me the same end result (including ability to adjust Mac volume via the OS) but without audio warping?

Comment: Which version of Soundflower? There are a few kicking around, by different authors. Rogue Amoeba I think even gave up hosting the old Cycling74 version now. Frankly, it's been flaky since about Mavericks - I gave up on it a long time ago. Audio Hijack or Loopback (both [Rogue Amoeba](https://rogueamoeba.com) ) would be modern [paid] alternatives.

Comment: I just gave Loopback a try but unfortunately it disables the Mac volume control when passing system audio through it.  This was actually the only reason I used SoundFlower, it did not have this issue.

Comment: Hmmm... idk then. I hadn't realised it did that; my rig has a hardware volume control so I never adjust at the Mac itself & actually I have system audio [beeps etc] always routed to the Mac's speaker, never through my audio rig.

Comment: I've got an email in to Rogue Amoeba asking about this issue, will update with whatever I find out from them.

Comment: RA are usually pretty good at responding, so keep us updated. Make sure I get pinged by the system by putting @Myname [it won't let me put my own name in as an example] somewhere in the response.

Comment: @Tetsujin well crud.  From RA - "Thanks for the feedback. Currently Loopback devices don't offer volume control, but it's a popular feature request. We'll see what happens with our future developments, so for now stay tuned for updates and let us know if you have any other feedback."

Comment: Ahh... a bit stuck then, I guess. Not really sure how we could even turn this into a useful answer either :/

Comment: Agreed... just hoping maybe someone else comes up with another option/suggestion.

Comment: Short of Googling for all the versions of Soundflower you can dredge up... see if one works better...

Comment: I suppose that's worth a shot, I didn't really think there was much difference between them except for minor differences for operating system compatibility. But I'll take a look… Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue may lie in SoundFlowerBed, not SoundFlower itself.  But since SFB is an abandoned project... it is unlikely to ever be made more robust.

Fortunately I think I've found a solution, which is [Sound Siphon](http://staticz.com/soundsiphon/).  I'm using it exactly as I would have with SoundFlower - routing my system sound and AirFoil to Sound Siphon, and sending Sound Siphon out to my audio interface.

Seems to be working perfectly, no audio warbling, and I can still adjust my overall system volume with the usual OS controls.  Plus, the demo version allows unlimited use of System Audio, which is all I was after... so this solution is even free!